# VBA sub works fine when ran by itself but does strange things (no errors though) when ran after before and after other macros

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code. It works fine when ran alone. However, when I run it alongside other subs (when I call several subs within one sub), it starts highlighting random cells and while it doesn't generate any errors, it doesn't work properly. I'm wondering if it's a timing issue but it still doesn't work when I add a lag...

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightAndHalve()
    Dim Cell As Range, rng As Range, A As Range, LastRow As Integer, Sales As Worksheet, R As Range, P As Range

    Set Sales = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Output")
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sheets("Sales Output").Range("Q6:Q" & LastRow)

    For Each Cell In rng
        On Error Resume Next
    
        Set P = Cell.Offset(0, -1)
        Set R = Cell.Offset(0, 1)
        If Cell.Value > 0 Then
            P.Value = P.Value / 2
            P.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            R.Value = 1
        End If
    Next Cell
    
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: The `On error resume next` is probably causing it to skip the setting of `P` and or `R` leading it to point to a previous cell. Try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: Remove that `On Error Resume Next` line and never use it unless you know what are you doing with it. Try running again and you should get some error

Comment: Hi Raymond, no error when I remove the on error statement. Same issue as before, works fine as an individual sub but not when called with others.

Comment: Can you give a specific example? What is the random cell that is highlighted? How is it different from the expected result? What are the other subroutines doing? As is, your current question does not contain a *reproducible* example.

Comment: @Lysander2001 You will need to describe what you mean by not working properly. Your `LastRow` is taking the range from the `ActiveSheet` because you did not fully qualify the range. Do you mean `Sales.Cells(Sales.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row`? Also `Set rng = Sales.Range("Q6:Q" & LastRow)`

Comment: Also dim `LastRow` as `Long` instead of`Integer`, you can get overflow if you have too many rows to process. (In fact you have no reason to use `Integer`, just declare `Long`)